# SQL counting all rows instead of counting individual rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement which requests data from the database.

```
SELECT `ID`, `To`, `Poster`, `Content`, `Time`, ifnull(`Aura`,0) as `Aura` FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages m
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Friend2 as Friend FROM friends WHERE Friend1 = '1'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Friend1 as Friend FROM friends WHERE Friend2 = '1'
        ) friends ON m.Poster = friends.`Friend`
        UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT *, '1' FROM messages where `Poster`='1'
    ) var
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select `ID` as `AuraID`, `Status` as `AuraStatus`, count(*) as `Aura`
            from messages_aura
    ) aura ON (var.Poster = aura.AuraID AND var.ID = aura.AuraStatus)
) final

GROUP BY `ID`, `Poster`
ORDER BY `Time` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Here is my `messages_aura` table layout. It shows `ID`, `Status` and `UserID`.

[image]

Here is the output from the above statement.

(The `ID` from the above screenshot refers to `Poster` below and the `Status` from the above screenshot refers to `ID` below)

[image]

The statement should give the bottom row a Aura count of `1` and the top row an Aura count of `2`. What's wrong?

Comment: You need `GROUP BY` in the subquery, don't you?

Comment: You're right! Thankyou, I can't believe it was that easy xD

Comment: I can't believe this problem is so common. We probably have to post this kind of answer several times a day.

Comment: mySQL's extended support of the group by is (IMO) the single greatest issue for most developers using aggregates and mysql.  This [extended support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) causes problems for most people.  I think we'd be better off having the feature disabled by default.  The database hides what would be an ANSII standard SQL error by having an aggregate w/o a group by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `GROUP BY`, so it's counting everything instead of grouping by some columns.

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    select `ID` as `AuraID`, `Status` as `AuraStatus`, count(*) as `Aura`
    from messages_aura
    GROUP BY AuraID, AuraStatus
) aura ON (var.Poster = aura.AuraID AND var.ID = aura.AuraStatus)
```