# Count joined revenues values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count revenues of each person from Germany and select the one who has the most of them.

It looks like the sum calculates all the revenues instead of each person's separately.

What am I doing wrong in here?

```
SELECT users.name, sum(revenues.value) as suma  FROM `users` 

JOIN revenues 
ON users.id = revenues.user_id

WHERE users.country = "de"

ORDER BY suma DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562925/sql-counting-all-rows-instead-of-counting-individual-rows/24562990#24562990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely use MySQL but it looks like you are missing a GROUP BY

```
SELECT users.name, sum(revenues.value) as suma  FROM `users` 

JOIN revenues 
ON users.id = revenues.user_id

WHERE users.country = "de"

GROUP BY users.name

ORDER BY suma DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a proper aggreagation function result you should use  group by

```
SELECT users.name, sum(revenues.value) as suma  
FROM `users` 
JOIN revenues ON users.id = revenues.user_id
WHERE users.country = "de"
group by  users.name 
ORDER BY suma DESC
LIMIT 1
```